# Active class for nav

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

I'm using the following script to add class="active" to my navigation menu and it works fine unless I use the htaccess to remove the .php extension.
This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var CurrentUrl = window.location.origin+window.location.pathname;
    $('#NavMenu a').each(function(Key,Value)
        {
            if(Value['href'] === CurrentUrl)
            {
                $(Value).parent().addClass('active');
            }
        });
 });
```

My .htaccess is the following

```
# remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)index$ $1 [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

Any suggested solutions? I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Remove the `.php` part from your `href`s?

Comment: I remove php extensions and I wanted to use script to show the active class. @Dr M J already gave me the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var CurrentUrl = window.location.origin+window.location.pathname + '.php';
```

But you will need to use htaccess by default or php extension will be added additionally

Comment: It works!! But to be honest I'm not sure what you mean by "you will need to use htaccess by default or php extension will be added additionally"

Comment: if you use var CurrentUrl = window.location.origin+window.location.pathname + '.php';  without htaccess to hide .php extension, Currenturl will be e.g. index.php.php or about-us.php.php   I mean double .php.php to script name will be added by javascript

Comment: I see. I always use htaccess to remove php extension so this is awesome, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @YarseoLLC This solution suggests solving a problem that could be prevented in the first place. However, if it answers your question, mark it as such please.

Comment: @AmmoPT how can this be prevented? I'd appreciate any feedback. Thanks!